# ionic 2: can I get data in json file, after error in http.post()?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to get data from json file after error of http.post(), to show error message that was posting in json file.
my code:

```
  this.http.post('my-url', postParams, options)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res.json());        
     }, error => {
      console.log(error);// Error getting the data
    });
```

in error time in json file, error message is sending but I cant get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is worked :

```
  this.http.post('my-url', postParams, options)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res.json());        
     }, error => {
       let err = error.json(); // this line added
       console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the same by using the `map` operator, like this:

```
this.http.post('my-url', postParams, options)
    .map(res => res.json())   // Get the body of the response here :)
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);  // <-- Use the response object directly        
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);     // <-- Use the error object directly
    });
```

Comment: thanks, but your code is same as my code in question,for this just using: 
   error.json()

Comment: Yes @M.Hajavi, it's pretty similar but the recommended way to obtain the body of the response (and the error) is by using the `map` operator instead of calling the `json()` method both in the response and in the error objects.

Comment: Could you please give us some more details about why is not working?

Comment: it does working same as my code in question and showing in console: Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …} but I want see inner message same as this: "your email not true"

Comment: Have you added the `.map(res => res.json())` (second line of code)?

Comment: @sabaferreras, with 'map' this showing: Response {_body: "{"email":["\u06cc\u06a9 \u0627\u06cc\u0645\u06cc\u…a9\u0633\u0627\u0646 \u0646\u06cc\u0633\u062a."]}", status: 422, ok: false, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …} but with error.json() showing: {email: Array(1), password: Array(1)} and then whit this: "hasOwnProperty('email')" I can get text in email

Comment: @sabaferreras, I think in both ways we need to .json()